# Using Anaconda Python 3.4 with PyQt5

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda, python-3.4, pyqt5

I have an existing PyQt5/Python3.4 application that works great, and would now like to add "real-time" data graphing to it.  Since matplotlib installation specifically looks for Python 3.2, and NumPhy / ipython each have there own Python version requirements, I thought I'd use a python distribution to avoid confusion.

But out of all the distros (pythonxy, winpython, canopy epd) Anaconda is the only one that supports Python 3.4, however it only has PyQt 4.10.4.   Is there a way I can install Anaconda, and use matplotlib from within my existing PyQt5 gui app?

Would I be better off just using another charting package (pyqtgraph, pyqwt, guiqwt, chaco, etc) that might work out of the box with PyQt5/Python3.4?

Comment: numphy?  Version 1.4.0 of matplotlib works with py3.4/qt5 (and should be released with in the week).  I don't know if conda has a build of qt5 yet though.  Am an not sure what you mean by 'look for 3.2', it uses what ever python you run setup.py with.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to install it from dsdale24's and asmeurer's channels but then, when trying to run a qt script with a QApplication object, I got an error message regarding to cocoa library not being found.

Then, following asmeurer's comment, I could install PyQt5 on anaconda with python 3.4 using the [mmcauliffe package](https://anaconda.org/mmcauliffe):

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/mmcauliffe pyqt5
```

Now it works great!

Comment: Can confirm that other channels were not compatible with python 3.4. This one worked! You can, in fact, check if the channel has a pyqt5 available for your OS and python version by checking the files tab of their pyqt5. [Example.](https://anaconda.org/dsdale24/pyqt5/files)

Answer (score 9):

We are working on adding pyqt5, but for now, you can install it from https://binstar.org/dsdale24/pyqt5.

```
conda config --add channels dsdale24 
conda install pyqt5
```

Comment: Sadly there's no Python 2.7 version for Windows at the moment

Comment: My understanding is that pyqt5 does not support Python 2.7 on Windows, because Python 2.7 extension modules have to be compiled with Visual Studio 2008. Even Riverbank doesn't have Python 2.7 Windows packages for pyqt5.

Comment: You can get PyQt5 for 2.7 without VS2008, but you have to recompile the whole python interpreter, so your versions match...  which makes it a little useless for anyone running the stock python interpreter.

Comment: This does not seem to be functional any more. The Qt5 and PyQt5 versions seem to be out of sync: 
    pyqt5: 5.3.2-py34_0
    qt5:   5.4.0-0
and import results in exception:     ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'

Comment: Maybe try one of the [other](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pyqt5) anaconda.org channels with pyqt5.

Answer (score 2):

create an env like this:

```
conda create –name my_env python=3.5 pyqt=5
```

works great.

Answer (score 1):

I use Anaconda and with Python v2.7.X and qt5 doesn't work. The work-around I found was 
Tools -> Preferences -> Python console -> External modules -> Library: PySlide